# Restriction of Picard group to the generic fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism of smooth projective complex algebraic varieties. Assume $f$ has connected fibres. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$ and let $X_\eta$ be the generic fibre of $f$. Consider the pullback map $$\imath^*\colon {\rm Pic}(X)\to {\rm Pic}(X_\eta)$$
induced by the morphism $\imath\colon X_\eta\to X$.
Questions:

1. Under which conditions is $\imath^*$ surjective?
2. Is the kernel of $\imath^*$ generated by line bundles corresponding to divisors whose support does not dominate $Y$?

Answer (score 6):

If $U$ is any open subset of $X$, there is an exact sequence
$$ \oplus\,\mathbb{Z} . D\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X)\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(U)\rightarrow 0$$ where the first sum is over the irreducible divisors supported in $X\smallsetminus U$ -- this follows easily from the description of $\mathrm{Pic}$ as divisors modulo linear equivalence. In your situation, taking  $U=f^{-1}(V)$ for $V$ open in $Y$ and passing to the limit, you get an exact sequence
$$ \oplus\,\mathbb{Z}. D\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X)\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X_{\eta })\rightarrow 0$$
where the first sum is now over all irreducible divisors which do not dominate $Y$.

Comment: The map on the left may not be an injection, though it it is irrelevant for this discussion.

Comment: I think it is injective. Just apply the snake lemma to the diagram of exact sequences where the first row is $0\rightarrow K_X^*/\mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow \oplus \,\mathbb{Z}.D\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X)\rightarrow 0$, and the second row the same replacing $X$ by $U$.

Comment: Many thanks. About passing to the limit, is there such an open subset $U\subseteq X$ with ${\rm Pic}(U)\simeq {\rm Pic}(X_\eta)$?

Comment: @abx What if you just remove like $33$ points from $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Oops! You (and Mohan) are right. I forgot that there are nontrivial invertible functions on $U$. I edit.

Comment: @pip: typically no. For instance if $B$ is a curve of genus $\geq 1$, $f^*\mathrm{Pic}(B)$ vanishes in $\mathrm{Pic}(X_{\eta })$ but not in $\mathrm{Pic}(U)$ for any $U$.

Comment: @abx: assume that $\oplus\mathbb{Z}.D = f^{*}Pic(Y)$. In this case is the map $\oplus\mathbb{Z}.D \rightarrow Pic(X)$ injective?

Comment: @Jack: I am not sure what is your question exactly: $f^*\operatorname{Pic}(Y) $ is by definition a subgroup of $\operatorname{Pic}(X) $.

Comment: @abx: I meant if all the divisors in $X$ that do not map dominantly onto $Y$ are pull-backs of divisors on $Y$.

Comment: Then this is false: take $Y=\mathbb{P}^1$, all the fibers have the same class in $\operatorname{Pic}(X) $.